# check if point is inside a rotated rectangle

Tags: python, rotation, collision-detection

I am trying to check if a point is inside a rotated rectangle.
I found: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128598/collision-detection-point-hitting-a-rotating-rectangle

but it doesnt work...
this is my python code:

```
    def collides(point_x, point_y, x_rect, y_rect, width_rect, height_rect, center_rect_x, center_rect_y, angle_rect):
        radians = angle_rect / 180.0 * math.pi
        angle_sin = math.sin(radians)
        angle_cos = math.cos(radians)

        x = ((point_x - center_rect_x) * angle_cos - (point_y - center_rect_y) * angle_sin) + center _rect_x
        y = ((point_x - center_rect_x) * angle_sin + (point_y - center_rect_y) * angle_cos) + center_rect_y

        return x > x_rect and x < x_rect + width_rect and y > y_rect and y < y_rect + height_rect
```

how can I check if a point collides a rotated rectangle?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Provide an example of how you're calling the `collides()` function, with the parameters. And explain _"it doesn't work"_. Also read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: looks like it's working, you have a typo `center _rect_x` should be `center_rect_x`